# Parse date from string and insert with Sqlalchemy tosqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy, datetime-parsing

My problem has two subproblems (is that a word?):

A. Parse date from string.

I have datetime from rss feed that has format like below:

```
u'Wed, 30 Sep 2015 18:59:39 +0000'
```

What is most 'pythonic' way to make a datetime from string above? I tried to do it with regex but I had about 20 lines of code to do that and I hope there is simplier way to do it, preferably without regex. I also don't know what is easy way to change `Sep` to `09`.

B. Insert to sqlite with Sqlalchemy

Here my problem is, I can't find example of code where I can see how to define column as datetime. Should it look like this?

```
t = Table('t', medatata, Column('my_date', Datetime)
```

And then just pass object of `datetime` to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A*. Look in to [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with appropriate [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
from datetime import datetime
fmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
datetime.strptime('Wed, 30 Sep 2015 18:59:39 +0000', fmt)
```

outputs

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 18, 59, 39, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

*B*. Yes, save the `datetime` object into the datebase.  For instance, you may have a *test* db defined as below.

```
class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, test_date=None):
        if test_date is None:
            test_date = datetime.utcnow()
```

then save your date as a variation of your original post.

```
rec = Test(datetime.strptime(...your RSS data here..., fmt))
```

The table def/saving may need tweaked a bit but it's the general idea. Also, some docs about [SQLAlchemy datatypes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DATETIME) and [SQLite Datatypes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.DATETIME).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get error while parsing that date: `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`
Do you know how to resolve this? I read that it's platform specific problem but nowhere I can find how to resolve this

Comment: I just did this:
    `d = 'Thu, 01 Oct 2015 14:29:08 +0000'`
    `dp = datetime.strptime(d[:-6], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %f')`
And it's good enough. Thanks!